# ASP.NET MVC4 data context class dropdown in mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, controller, datacontext

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 to create a project and also want to use a SQL Server database.

When I am trying to add a controller, two dropdowns show up:

1. Model class
2. Data Context class

I know about model class but I don't have any idea about the Data Context class.
Please guide me - what should I select from dropdown of Data Context class? There are four to five options in dropdown.

[image: Here is snapshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data context` is a class derived from `DbContext`. Using it, you specify your database model for them, and in this way, your methods are determined based on the entered `Data Context`.